# How to get JSON value to variable?

Tags: android, json

This is my json value,

```
{"test":"ruslan","status":"OK"}
```

How to get "test" value?

And this is my httpclient code to acces api

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.setBasicAuth("user01", "pwd01");
client.get("http://localhost/web/api/getsession", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {

        // in this section, I want to store test value from json to a variable

      @Override
      public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
              Log.d("Status", "failure");
          }
      });
```

Comment: 1) `http://localhost/web/` isn't going to work 2) Where is the JSON string in your app? You need to convert a `byte[]` to a string first, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this

```
    String json = "{\"test\":\"ruslan\",\"status\":\"OK\"}";
    String test = "";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        test = jsonObject.getString("test");
    }catch (JSONException je){
        je.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("test : " + test);
```

Answer (score 0):

First get ur json from server by connecting to it

```
DefaultHttpClient   httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(http://someJSONUrl/jsonWebService);
// Depends on your web service
httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

InputStream inputStream = null;
String result = null;
try {
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);           
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    inputStream = entity.getContent();
    // json is UTF-8 by default
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    result = sb.toString();
} catch (Exception e) { 
    // Oops
}
finally {
    try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
}
```

now you have your JSON, so what?

Create a JSONObject:

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

To get a specific string

```
String aJsonString = jObject.getString("test");
```

Comment: JSON doesn't always come from a website

Comment: since the guy hasn't told the source of the json i assumed it that it comes from a web service @cricket_007

Comment: Sure, but that extra detail shouldn't really matter, right? The question asked how to parse JSON, not fetch data from a URL

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample for how to parse json.

```
    {
   "sys":
   {
      "country":"GB",
      "sunrise":1381107633,
      "sunset":1381149604
   },
   "weather":[
      {
         "id":711,
         "main":"Smoke",
         "description":"smoke",
         "icon":"50n"
      }
   ],

  "main":
   {
      "temp":304.15,
      "pressure":1009,
   }
}
```

Java code

```
 JSONObject sys  = reader.getJSONObject("sys");
country = sys.getString("country");

JSONObject main  = reader.getJSONObject("main");
temperature = main.getString("temp");
```

For More Detail see [This Demo](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm)

Comment: Why not just answer the question?

Comment: @cricket_007 what you say not getting you?

Comment: The question showed example JSON asking how to get one value. This may answer how to parse JSON, but doesn't answer the question that was really asked